# Shorthand way to append multiple dynamic key names to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find myself making (potentially) more work for myself, by having to specify each dynamic key one line at a time.

What I am doing now to add additional keys to an existing object:

```
create_request[('title_' + id)] = field_data[0];
create_request[('field_' + id)] = field_data[1];
```

What I was hoping to be able to do is something like:

```
jQuery.extend({('title_' + id) : field_data[0], ('field_' + id) : field_data[1]});
```

Is there an easier way than what I am doing now (since what I was hoping would work doesn't)? Or is this just a limitation of the language?

Edit for clarity:

Okay, so you can create an object in javascript like this:

```
{
 a : 1
}
```

But that assumes that a is the string value for the key. What if I wanted the key to be the value of a variable?

I could do:

```
the_object[variable] = 1
```

But what if I wanted to do more than one of these dynamic insertions into the object? Is there a convenient way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically  Not quite a duplicate, but is along the lines of what you want.  You could use your `create_request` object, and a new object with all of your fields in it, and merge them together.

Comment: @Brad, maybe I wasn't clear, but that question isn't similar at all. I am aware that you can merge two objects together (I even used jquery's extend in the example).

Comment: @Brad, in response to your edit: I don't see how that would be a shorthand solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking then, sorry.

Comment: not finding this clear at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I could change just one thing about JavaScript, it would be object literal syntax. I think the property names should be evaluated as expressions the same as the property values; I think the benefits of this would outway the nuisance of being forced to include quoted property names when using static names. But, if wishes were fishes...

Using the square-bracket notation is the only built-in way to set properties with dynamic names, but it is not difficult to create your own function that takes input very similar to the syntax you hoped to use:

```
extendObject(obj, props) {
   for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i+=2)
      obj[props[i]] = props[i+1];
}

extendObject(create_request, ['title_' + id, field_data[0], 'field_' + id, field_data[1]]);
```

By using an *array* rather than a plain object to hold the new property names and values you can use dynamic names.

(Note also that even with the square-bracket syntax in your question you've made it slightly more complicated than it needs to be by including redundant parentheses.)

Comment: You are two for two tonight with me. I think you might be the only person who understands what I'm saying :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object#assign` as follows:

```
Object.assign( create_request, {[`title_${id}`]:field_data[0], [`field_${id}`]:field_data[1]} );
```

**DEMO**

```js
let create_request = {a:1}, field_data = [5,79,59,100,3090], id = 3;

Object.assign( create_request, {[`title_${id}`]:field_data[0], [`field_${id}`]:field_data[1]} );

console.log( create_request );
```